# Google Apps Script - setting Line spacing and Heading1 in a table cell

Tags: google-apps-script

Thanks to @Tanaike for providing answers to my previous question.  I have 2 other issues.

1 - When set spacing is 1 but when check in Google Doc, the spacing was 1.15.

```html
heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;
```

2 - I tried to set DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.Heading1 to the following but it does not works.

```html
tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).editAsText().setAttributes(heading1Style);
```

The following is the whole code.

```html
function insertHeading1() {
  var heading1Style = {};
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var cells = [
    [' ', 'HEADING 1, CALIBRI, 18PT, BOLD, LEFT ALIGNED, ALL CAPS, SINGLE SPACING, NO SPACE BEFORE AND AFTER PARAGRAPH'],
  ];

  var tableRow1 = body.appendTable(cells);
  tableRow1.setColumnWidth(0, 10);
  tableRow1.getCell(0, 0).setBackgroundColor('#1c3a69');
  tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).editAsText().setAttributes(heading1Style);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are setting the declared style attributes to a [TableCell object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell). However you cannot change Line Spacing of a TableCell object directly in Google Docs.
- What you can do instead is add a Paragragph object on that cell and then modify the lineSpacing. To do that, you can call the method [insertParagraph(childIndex, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#insertparagraphchildindex,-text) of the TableCell object of the second table cell.

I've slightly modified the sample code:

```js
function insertHeading1() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var heading1Style = {};
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
  // heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;
  heading1Style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var cells = [
    ['', ''],
  ];

  var tableRow1 = body.appendTable(cells);
  tableRow1.setColumnWidth(0, 10);
  tableRow1.getCell(0, 0).setBackgroundColor('#1c3a69');
  tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).setAttributes(heading1Style);
  tableRow1.getCell(0, 1)
      .insertParagraph(0, 'HEADING 1, CALIBRI, 18PT, BOLD, LEFT ALIGNED, ALL CAPS, SINGLE SPACING, NO SPACE BEFORE AND AFTER PARAGRAPH')
      .setLineSpacing(1);
  tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).removeChild(tableRow1.getCell(0, 1).getChild(1)); // deletes the additional paragraph created by appendTable()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo.  Your amendment works and I also resolved the Heading issues.  The thing here is after inserting the para in the cell, the cursor to "enter" next line  Anyway to remove that?   HEADING 1, CALIBRI, 18PT, BOLD, LEFT ALIGNED, ALL CAPS, SINGLE SPACING, NO SPACE BEFORE AND AFTER PARAGRAPH
<enter>

Comment: @user1787756 Edited my answer with a fix to delete the additional line. Please remember to accept the answer if it helped you. Cheers!